# Actionbar Sherlock Search Widget expand does not work

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Actionbar Sherlock. The activity be shown on startup should start in a "search mode" to start searching immediately. For doing so I use the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    //collapse search
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.string.inlineSearch, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.inlineSearch)).setIcon(R.drawable.menu_search);
    searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    searchView = new SearchView(this);
    searchItem.setActionView(new SearchView(this));
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    return true;
}
```

The SearchView is the View provided by Android / Actionbar Sherlock.

The problem I'm facing with that is that no matter what I do, the item is never expanded on startup. 
I tried calling the expandActionView method after startup by using another actionbar item, nothing changed.
I implemented my own View implementing CollapsibleActionView, but the methods onActionViewExpanded() and onActionViewCollapsed() never get called.

But if I click the collapsed button of the SearchView, the view expands as expected.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14):

After going through the source documentation I finally found the answer by myself.
`menuItem.expandActionView()` only takes effect if the MenuItem has set the following flag: `searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);`

Hope that helps somebody out there!

Comment: were u able to expand the search box to the full width of the action bar ?

Comment: Were you in this answer still using the Action Bar Sherlock search view or your own custom view you mentioned above?

Comment: The only difference was the change of the setShowAsAction, the view was still the search view provided by actionbar sherlock

Comment: I was expanding the search widget incorrectly and using setIconifiedByDefault instead of using expandActionView....this fixed my issue!